# Dropdownlist control value not saving to database

Tags: c#, sql, drop-down-menu

I have two dropdownlist controls on an add/edit form page, one for countries (called CountryCode) and one for regions/states (called ProvinceCode). The code has been set up so that, when users select "United States" from the country dropdownlist, then the region dropdownlist is populated with all valid US states. If the user selects "Canada" from the country dropdownlist, then the region dropdownlist is populated with valid provinces. This functionality works fine, but when "Canada" is selected, for some reason, the region dropdownlist's value is never saved to the database. I am not sure why this is, especially since I can save US states just fine.

This is the code that is meant to populate the country and region dropdownlists:

```
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CountryCode.DataSource = CountryDataSource.LoadAll("Name");
        CountryCode.DataBind();

        InitCountryAndProvince();

    }

    private void InitCountryAndProvince()
    {
        //MAKE SURE THE CORRECT ADDRESS IS SELECTED
        Address address = this.Address;
        bool foundCountry = false;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(address.CountryCode))
        {
            ListItem selectedCountry = CountryCode.Items.FindByValue(address.CountryCode);
            if (selectedCountry != null)
            {
                CountryCode.SelectedIndex = CountryCode.Items.IndexOf(selectedCountry);
                foundCountry = true;
            }
        }
        if (!foundCountry)
        {
            Warehouse defaultWarehouse = AbleContext.Current.Store.DefaultWarehouse;
            ListItem selectedCountry = CountryCode.Items.FindByValue(defaultWarehouse.CountryCode);
            if (selectedCountry != null) CountryCode.SelectedIndex = CountryCode.Items.IndexOf(selectedCountry);
        }
        //MAKE SURE THE PROVINCE LIST IS CORRECT FOR THE COUNTRY
        UpdateCountry();
        //NOW LOOK FOR THE PROVINCE TO SET
        ListItem selectedProvince = ProvinceCode.Items.FindByValue(address.Province);
        if (selectedProvince != null) ProvinceCode.SelectedIndex = ProvinceCode.Items.IndexOf(selectedProvince);

    }

    private void UpdateCountry()
    {
        //SEE WHETHER POSTAL CODE IS REQUIRED
        string[] countries = AbleContext.Current.Store.Settings.PostalCodeCountries.Split(",".ToCharArray());
        //PostalCodeRequired.Enabled = (Array.IndexOf(countries, Country.SelectedValue) > -1);
        //SEE WHETHER PROVINCE LIST IS DEFINED
        IList<Province> provinces = ProvinceDataSource.LoadForCountry(CountryCode.SelectedValue);
        if (provinces.Count > 0)
        {
            IEnumerable<Province> sortedProvinces = provinces.OrderBy(f => f.Name);
            provinces = sortedProvinces.ToList();
            ProvinceCode.Visible = false;
            ProvinceCode.Visible = true;
            ProvinceCode.Items.Clear();
            ProvinceCode.Items.Add(string.Empty);
            foreach (Province province in provinces)
            {
                string provinceValue = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(province.ProvinceCode) ? province.ProvinceCode : province.Name);
                ProvinceCode.Items.Add(new ListItem(province.Name, provinceValue));
            }
            ListItem selectedProvince = FindSelectedProvince();
            if (selectedProvince != null) selectedProvince.Selected = true;
            ProvinceCode.Enabled = true;
            ProvinceCode.Text = string.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            ProvinceCode.Visible = true;
            ProvinceCode.Visible = false;
            ProvinceCode.Items.Clear();
            //Province2Required.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private ListItem FindSelectedProvince()
    {
        string defaultValue = ProvinceCode.Text;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(defaultValue)) defaultValue = Request.Form[ProvinceCode.UniqueID];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(defaultValue)) return null;
        defaultValue = defaultValue.ToUpperInvariant();
        foreach (ListItem item in ProvinceCode.Items)
        {
            string itemText = item.Text.ToUpperInvariant();
            string itemValue = item.Value.ToUpperInvariant();
            if (itemText == defaultValue || itemValue == defaultValue) return item;
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void Country_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //UPDATE THE FORM FOR THE NEW COUNTRY
        UpdateCountry();
    }
```

This is the section of the save method that contains the country and region dropdownlist controls:

```
    private void SaveCustomerInfo(int CustID)
    {
        int currentUserID = AbleContext.Current.UserId;
        string editQuery = "UPDATE Customers SET BillToRegion = @BillToRegion, BillToCountry = @BillToCountry WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID";
        string addQuery = "INSERT INTO Customers (BillToRegion, BillToCountry) VALUES(@BillToRegion, @BillToCountry)";
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AbleCommerce"].ToString()))
            {
                cn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = cn;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@BillToRegion", ProvinceCode.SelectedValue));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@BillToCountry",  CountryCode.SelectedValue));

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cn.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Logger.Warn("Admin\\People\\Customers\\EditCustomer.aspx - SaveCustomerInfo", exception);

            }
```

And this is the code that is called when the page loads to populate fields with values from the database (if the user is editing an existing entry):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _CustomerID = AlwaysConvert.ToInt(Request.QueryString["CustomerID"]);
        int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["CustomerID"], out _CustomerID);

        if (_CustomerID == 0)
        {

            AddBtn.Visible = true;
            EditBtn.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            custIDHidden.Value = _CustomerID.ToString();
            AddBtn.Visible = false;
            EditBtn.Visible = true;

        }
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (_CustomerID != 0)
            {

                string selectQuery = "BillToRegion, BillToCountry FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID";
                try
                {
                    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AbleCommerce"].ToString()))
                    {
                        cn.Open();
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, cn);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CustomerID", custIDHidden.Value));

                        using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                ProvinceCode.SelectedValue = reader["BillToRegion"].ToString();
                                CountryCode.SelectedValue = reader["BillToCountry"].ToString();


                            }
                        }
                        cn.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception x)
                {
                    Logger.Warn("Admin\\People\\Customers\\EditCustomer.aspx - Page_Load", x);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();` in SaveCustomerInfo? You are not using any of the two query strings there. C&P error?

Comment: Oh, sorry--I excluded the bit that checks for which query is needed. There is more information being saved to the database from the form, but there is a lot--and I do mean a lot of fields. To keep things simple, I removed the references to other fields from the INSERT, UPDATE and SELECT methods and only left the Country and Region ones.

Comment: Is it possible that the code run on `Page_Init` should only be run on initial load? Normally you would check for `isPostBack` and only re-bind controls under these circumstances (or at times when something has been changed). The fact that US entries are being saved suggests that this isn't the issue (hence adding as a comment rather than an answer) but it might be worth checking as re-binding controls every time you post back can often cause erratic results.